# Connection refused on ipv6 server

Tags: django, server, ipv6

I'm making a little side project with Django and i want to acces this local server from outside my lan. So I decided to try ipv6

I set   `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]`  and run the server as `python manage.py runserver --ipv6 "[::1]:8000"`, but i can't access it from another pc (even from the ones i could with ipv4, connected to my wifi). I get the Connection Refused error in the browser.

And yes, my port is open in the firewall (`sudo ufw allow 8000`)

One last thing, checking with wireshark, i found the TCP packages get to the server. A RST flag is sent.

Answer (score 0):

The `::1` address is the loopback address, and packets with that address cannot exist on a network outside the host. It cannot be used as either a source or destination address on a network. I think you meant to use the `::` unspecified address that will listen on all host addresses.